# Partitioning and selecting a value in Snowflake based on distance from date

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datediff, partition

I have a billion row dataset which is constantly building with more repeat data on customers.

```
ID   creation_date          report_date             status
001  2021-01-20T00:22:06Z   2021-02-02T00:22:06Z    ACTIVE
002  2021-01-30T00:22:06Z   2021-02-02T00:22:06Z    ACTIVE
003  2021-02-01T00:22:06Z   2021-02-02T00:22:06Z    ACTIVE
001  2021-01-20T00:22:06Z   2021-02-02T00:23:06Z    ACTIVE
002  2021-01-30T00:22:06Z   2021-02-02T00:23:06Z    ACTIVE
003  2021-02-01T00:22:06Z   2021-02-02T00:23:06Z    ACTIVE
001  2021-01-20T00:22:06Z   2021-02-19T00:22:06Z    ACTIVE
002  2021-01-30T00:22:06Z   2021-02-19T00:22:06Z    ACTIVE
003  2021-02-01T00:22:06Z   2021-02-19T00:22:06Z    ACTIVE
001  2021-01-20T00:22:06Z   2021-02-20T00:22:06Z    ACTIVE
002  2021-01-30T00:22:06Z   2021-02-20T00:22:06Z    EXPIRED
003  2021-02-01T00:22:06Z   2021-02-20T00:22:06Z    EXPIRED
001  2021-01-20T00:22:06Z   2021-02-21T00:22:06Z    ACTIVE
002  2021-01-30T00:22:06Z   2021-02-21T00:22:06Z    EXPIRED
003  2021-02-01T00:22:06Z   2021-02-21T00:22:06Z    EXPIRED
001  2021-01-20T00:22:06Z   2021-02-30T00:22:06Z    ACTIVE
002  2021-01-30T00:22:06Z   2021-02-30T00:22:06Z    EXPIRED
003  2021-02-01T00:22:06Z   2021-02-30T00:22:06Z    EXPIRED
001  2021-01-20T00:22:06Z   2021-03-01T00:22:06Z    ACTIVE
002  2021-01-30T00:22:06Z   2021-03-01T00:22:06Z    EXPIRED
003  2021-02-01T00:22:06Z   2021-03-01T00:22:06Z    ACTIVE
001  2021-01-20T00:22:06Z   2021-03-22T00:22:06Z    EXPIRED
002  2021-01-30T00:22:06Z   2021-03-22T00:22:06Z    EXPIRED
003  2021-02-01T00:22:06Z   2021-03-22T00:22:06Z    EXPIRED
```

Each report_date indicates a date where all records were updated to their current status. Like a pulse check.

And all I would like is the **last status of which the user was during the week after a month from creation date (week 5).**

As an example: ID = 001.

Here we see their creation date is `2021-01-20`, meaning one month from this date is `2021-02-20`. I would like to know:

- What was the final status of this user during the report dates between `2021-02-20` and `2021-02-27`?

You can see in the above data that Active remained active in all of the reports between `2021-02-20` and `2021-02-27` (that are listed.)

To make things simple, we only want to know the LAST change of status in this time frame. Notice in ID=003, they swapped to `ACTIVE` on `2021-02-22', so though they were` EXPIRED` the day before, they switched back to active within the boundary.

Anything after a week after the month (anything after 5 weeks) is irrelevant.

You also may notice that 1 month from `2021-01-30` is `2021-02-30` which doesnt make sense. In these cases, use the final date of the month, or `2021-02-28`.

Final output:

```
ID    week_5_status
001          ACTIVE   
002         EXPIRED
003          ACTIVE
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was trying to filter all the data to just the 5 week mark, then parttion and select the latest status in that bunch. But struggling to do it with all records

Comment: How have you ended up with `report_date` on "Feb 30". What are the data types of those columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert the text values (presumably) to valid datetime values. Then, filter the rows such that report_datetime is fewer than 6 weeks after creation_datetime. Take the max of that filtered list, then join back to the original data to get the status for the row with the max value.

```
CREATE TABLE t (id int, creation_date VARCHAR(19), report_date VARCHAR(19), status text);
INSERT INTO t (id,creation_date,report_date,status) VALUES 
(1,'2021-01-20T00:22:06','2021-02-02T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
(2,'2021-01-30T00:22:06','2021-02-02T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
(3,'2021-02-01T00:22:06','2021-02-02T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
(1,'2021-01-20T00:22:06','2021-02-02T00:23:06','ACTIVE'),
(2,'2021-01-30T00:22:06','2021-02-02T00:23:06','ACTIVE'),
(3,'2021-02-01T00:22:06','2021-02-02T00:23:06','ACTIVE'),
(1,'2021-01-20T00:22:06','2021-02-19T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
(2,'2021-01-30T00:22:06','2021-02-19T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
(3,'2021-02-01T00:22:06','2021-02-19T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
(1,'2021-01-20T00:22:06','2021-02-20T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
(2,'2021-01-30T00:22:06','2021-02-20T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
(3,'2021-02-01T00:22:06','2021-02-20T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
(1,'2021-01-20T00:22:06','2021-02-21T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
(2,'2021-01-30T00:22:06','2021-02-21T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
(3,'2021-02-01T00:22:06','2021-02-21T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
(1,'2021-01-20T00:22:06','2021-02-30T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
(2,'2021-01-30T00:22:06','2021-02-30T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
(3,'2021-02-01T00:22:06','2021-02-30T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
(1,'2021-01-20T00:22:06','2021-03-01T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
(2,'2021-01-30T00:22:06','2021-03-01T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
(3,'2021-02-01T00:22:06','2021-03-01T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
(1,'2021-01-20T00:22:06','2021-03-22T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
(2,'2021-01-30T00:22:06','2021-03-22T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
(3,'2021-02-01T00:22:06','2021-03-22T00:22:06','EXPIRED');


WITH dat
AS
(
SELECT id
, CAST(creation_date AS datetime) AS creation_datetime
, CAST(REPLACE(report_date,'02-30','02-28') AS datetime) AS report_datetime
, status
FROM t
),
dat2
AS
(
SELECT id
,MAX(report_datetime) AS max_report_datetime
FROM dat
WHERE DATEDIFF(week,creation_datetime,report_datetime) < 6
GROUP BY id
)
SELECT dat.*
FROM dat
     INNER JOIN dat2 
             ON dat.id = dat2.id 
            AND dat.report_datetime = dat2.max_report_datetime;
```

[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5c64bb843d89ed11f14246a72adb1faa)

Answer (score 0):

[QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) and [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html) seem to be what you want to select the "last state inside the window"

So with a CTE for `data`, which I changed a couple of invalid `report_date` to be real dates. Perhaps in the wrong direction, but it doesn't impact the SQL.

```
 WITH data(id,creation_date,report_date,status)AS (
     SELECT column1
        ,to_date(column2, 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mi:ss')
        ,to_date(column3, 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mi:ss')
        ,column4 
     FROM VALUES 
    (1,'2021-01-20T00:22:06','2021-02-02T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
    (2,'2021-01-30T00:22:06','2021-02-02T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
    (3,'2021-02-01T00:22:06','2021-02-02T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
    (1,'2021-01-20T00:22:06','2021-02-02T00:23:06','ACTIVE'),
    (2,'2021-01-30T00:22:06','2021-02-02T00:23:06','ACTIVE'),
    (3,'2021-02-01T00:22:06','2021-02-02T00:23:06','ACTIVE'),
    (1,'2021-01-20T00:22:06','2021-02-19T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
    (2,'2021-01-30T00:22:06','2021-02-19T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
    (3,'2021-02-01T00:22:06','2021-02-19T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
    (1,'2021-01-20T00:22:06','2021-02-20T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
    (2,'2021-01-30T00:22:06','2021-02-20T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
    (3,'2021-02-01T00:22:06','2021-02-20T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
    (1,'2021-01-20T00:22:06','2021-02-21T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
    (2,'2021-01-30T00:22:06','2021-02-21T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
    (3,'2021-02-01T00:22:06','2021-02-21T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
    (1,'2021-01-20T00:22:06','2021-02-28T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
    (2,'2021-01-30T00:22:06','2021-02-28T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
    (3,'2021-02-01T00:22:06','2021-02-28T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
    (1,'2021-01-20T00:22:06','2021-03-01T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
    (2,'2021-01-30T00:22:06','2021-03-01T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
    (3,'2021-02-01T00:22:06','2021-03-01T00:22:06','ACTIVE'),
    (1,'2021-01-20T00:22:06','2021-03-22T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
    (2,'2021-01-30T00:22:06','2021-03-22T00:22:06','EXPIRED'),
    (3,'2021-02-01T00:22:06','2021-03-22T00:22:06','EXPIRED')
)
```

The main SQL becomes:

```
SELECT d.id
    ,d.creation_date
    ,d.report_date
    ,d.status
FROM data AS d
WHERE dateadd(week,5,d.creation_date) >= d.report_date
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by id order by report_date desc) = 1 ;
```

gives:

| ID | CREATION_DATE | REPORT_DATE | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-20 | 2021-02-21 | ACTIVE |
| 2 | 2021-01-30 | 2021-03-01 | EXPIRED |
| 3 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-03-01 | ACTIVE |

Or you literally want only the two columns:

```
SELECT d.id
    ,d.status
FROM data AS d
WHERE dateadd(week,5,d.creation_date) >= d.report_date
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by id order by report_date desc) = 1 ;
```

gives:

| ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ACTIVE |
| 2 | EXPIRED |
| 3 | ACTIVE |